# On the new minecraft it wont allow me to tame an ocelot they aren't even afraid of me is it a bug or what?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Everytime i find a wild ocelot its totally chill and doesnt run away or anything. And then when i bring out the raw fish and crouch and wait it doesn't come to me or anything. 
It'll start to crouch but even when i don't move or anything it just stops and goes away. 
Does anyone know if this is just a bug or something ?
 
Please let me know and btw when i feed it normally it goes into breed mode.

Comment: On one side you say that they are not scared of you, on the other side you say that they go away. So what is it?

Comment: Also, what is "the new Minecraft"?

Comment: It sounds like you are in creative mode.  Are you in creative mode?  In creative, they will take food, enter breeding mode, and are not afraid of you. I don't know for sure that they can't be in creative but I've never been able to tame one in creative.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're using the new snapshot, 1.14. My only guess of what is happening is that ocelots are no longer tamed into cats - instead you can only make wild cats tame cats. Ocelots will, however, trust you - they just don't transform colors.

If they aren't afraid of you but they aren't coming to you it COULD be a bug. I've tried to tame them in creative mode and they have ran away. Maybe you can find a solution at minecraft.gamepedia.com/ocelot